# Make elements pulsate in sequence

Tags: jquery

I need to make each images called transparent.png pulsate (or fadein, fadeout) 3 times in sequence right after each other not on the same time as it does now.

transparent.png lays on top of each image and gives an fade out effect.

I use:

- jQuery 1.7.2
- jQuery UI 1.8.21

Here is my code:

```
jQuery('.transparent').each(function(index) {
    jQuery(this).effect("pulsate", {times:3}, 1000);
});

<div id="content">
    <a class="frontimage projectleft" href="?folder=/sculptures">
        <img width="200" title="" alt="" src="0054_46.jpg">
        <img width="200" title="" alt="" src="transparent.png" class="transparent" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
    </a>
    <a class="frontimage projectleft" href="?folder=/furniture">
        <img width="200" title="" alt="" src="0076_20.jpg">
        <img width="200" title="" alt="" src="transparent.png" class="transparent" style="opacity: 1;">
    </a>
    <a class="frontimage projectright" href="?folder=/paintings">
        <img width="200" title="" alt="" src="156_52.jpg">
        <img width="200" title="" alt="" src="transparent.png" class="transparent" style="opacity: 1;">
    </a>
    <a class="frontimage projectleft" href="?folder=/sculptures">
        <img width="200" title="" alt="" src="174_36.jpg">
        <img width="200" title="" alt="" src="transparent.png" class="transparent" style="opacity: 1;">
    </a>
    <a class="frontimage projectleft" href="?folder=/furniture">
        <img width="200" title="" alt="" src="276_1.jpg">
        <img width="200" title="" alt="" src="transparent.png" class="transparent" style="opacity: 1;">
    </a>
    <a class="frontimage projectright" href="?folder=/paintings">
        <img width="200" title="" alt="" src="290_200076-01.jpg">
        <img width="200" title="" alt="" src="transparent.png" class="transparent" style="opacity: 1;">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to chain the next call to `effect()` in the callback you provide to the current call.

To achieve this, I would suggest creating a function that takes a set of elements and the index of the one you wish to animate:

```
function pulsate(elements, index)
{
    if (index < elements.length) {
        elements.eq(index).effect("pulsate", {
            times: 3
        }, 1000, function() {
            pulsate(elements, ++index);
        });
    }
}
```

Then initiating the sequence by issuing:

```
pulsate(jQuery(".transparent"), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but the principal is sound.

```
pulsate(jQuery('.transparent').first());    // Call this to pulsate each image sequentially

function pulsate(element)
{
    jQuery(element).effect("pulsate", {times:3}, 1000, function ()
    {
        var _next = $(element).parent().next();
        if (_next.length != 0)
            pulsate(_next.find('.transparent'));
    });
}
```

You're basically using the callback on the effect function to set the next element in the series pulsating.